# Role of quantum fluctuation of light in lasers: simple explanation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-information, laser

Firstly, I am not an expert and have no background in quantum physics and in physics. I am studying laser technology and have found out that the quantum fluctuation of light will be a limitation of the detection even if we have a good semiconductor.

I have read in [Wikipedia, this effect changes with respect to the amount of energy in a point in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). Honestly, I understood only this sentence. I tried to find another information about this effect: for example this paper: Quantum Fluctuations of Light: [A Modern Perspective on Wave/Particle Duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104073). It was explained with a thousand math expressions that make the information not understandable for me.

Could someone explain to me what the quantum fluctuation of light is and why it is important for lasers?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to detect. I think the question needs more specific: if you could explain a setup/experiment that you ahve in mind, one could give a clear answer.